# Could not compile my first Maven project as provided in the Apache tutorial

Tags: java, maven, compilation

https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

This is the tutorial I am using, following which I successfully created my own application Hey3

java version: 17.0.2

maven version: 3.8.5

However the next step ("mvn package") generated the following "compilation failure"

[compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY0oj.jpg)

This is the default pom.xml generated by the system:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.peter.2nd</groupId>
  <artifactId>Hey3</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>Hey3</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF- 8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
         </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

The App.java mentioned in the error message is like the following (as opened in Sublime):

```
 package com.peter.2nd;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

The official tutorial mentioned aboved states that there could be problems with an old version of maven-compiler-plugin and provides their suggested pom.xml settings. I copied those settings into my pom.xml and it did not solve the problem

However now I vaguely realized it could be because of the version of the compiler. I googled some solutions, copied those settings into my pom.xml (sorry this is all I could do as a new learner) and none of them worked

This latest pom.xml is the best I could do after reading some info about configuration and the error still persists

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.10.1</version>
  <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
```

```
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Please help me

Comment: First don't link to images better copy&paste the text output of the error message and furthermore the compiler-plugin as a dependency is wrong.. based on the error message I would say you`App.java` contains the problem.. please show the source code of your app file...

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for your reply. I have posted the App.java file. It was generated as part of the official "template" (is archetype the correct term?), not written by me

Comment: Change the package name `com.peter.2nd;` because `2nd` is not allowed

Comment: @khmarbaise That seems to be the problem! I really don't know what to say. Many thanks

Comment: appreciate to help. Check the answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the given package name  `package com.peter.2nd;` which is not allowed becaue `2nd` is not allowed.